# Error al imprimir: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, array, arraylist, numpy

Me esta dando un error al querer imprimir el numero en donde se encuentra la combinacion que deseo, al final tambien se puede observar lo que quiero imprimir relmente, solo debo resolver el problema de poder imprimir la un elemento de la lista en base a su ubicacion

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import array
import itertools

velocidades = np.array([1,2,3])
angulos = np.array([4,5,6])
combinaciones_no_usadas = list(itertools.product(velocidades,angulos))

combinacion_usada = []
lista_radio_de_giro = []
lista_turn_rate = []


while combinaciones_no_usadas:
    combinacion = combinaciones_no_usadas[0]
    velocidad_en_knots = combinacion[0]*1.94384
    bank_angle = math.radians(combinacion[1])
    turn_rate = (1091*math.tan(bank_angle))/velocidad_en_knots
    radio_de_giro = (velocidad_en_knots**2)/(36.94*math.tan(bank_angle))
    combinacion_usada.append(combinacion)
    lista_radio_de_giro.append(radio_de_giro)
    lista_turn_rate.append(turn_rate)
    combinaciones_no_usadas.pop(0)
minimo_turn_rate = min(lista_turn_rate)
minimo_radio_de_giro = min(lista_radio_de_giro)
combinacion_turn_rate_min = np.where(min(lista_turn_rate))
combinacion_radio_de_giro_min = np.where(min(lista_radio_de_giro))

**print =(combinacion_usada[combinacion_radio_de_giro_min])**

# print("La combinacion ", combinacion_usada[combinacion_radio_de_giro_min] , " tiene el radio de giro menor ", minimo_radio_de_giro , "aunque tiene un turn rate de ", lista_turn_rate[combinacion_radio_de_giro_min])
# print()
# print("La combinacion ", combinacion_usada[combinacion_turn_rate_min] ," tiene el turn rate menor ", minimo_turn_rate ," aunque tiene un radio de giro de", lista_radio_de_giro[combinacion_turn_rate_min])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.where` retorna una tupla de array en este caso, por lo que intentas usar eso como índice, lo cual no es posible como el error muestra. Deberías hacer:

```
print(combinacion_usada[combinacion_radio_de_giro_min[0][0]])
```

No obstante usa mal `numpy.where`, siempre te va retornar 0, debería ser algo como:

```
combinacion_turn_rate_min = np.where(combinaciones_usadas == min(lista_turn_rate))[0]
combinacion_radio_de_giro_min = np.where(combinaciones_usadas == min(lista_radio_de_giro))[0]
```

Dicho ésto, el algoritmo es muy ineficiente especialemnte por usar un ciclo while y `list.pop` + `list.append`, más aun cuando usas NumPy pero no lo aprovechas. Puedes realizar todas las operaciones de forma vectorizada:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np



velocidades = np.array([1, 2, 3])
angulos = np.array([4, 5, 6])
combinaciones = np.array(list(itertools.product(velocidades, angulos)))
velocidades_en_knots = combinaciones[:, 0] * 1.94384
bank_angles = np.radians(combinaciones[:, 1])
turn_rates = (1091 * np.tan(bank_angles)) / velocidades_en_knots
radios_de_giro = (velocidades_en_knots ** 2) / (36.94 * np.tan(bank_angles))

minimo_turn_rate = turn_rates.min()
minimo_radio_de_giro = radios_de_giro.min()
minimo_turn_rate_idx = np.argmin(turn_rates)
minimo_radio_de_giro_idx = np.argmin(radios_de_giro)

print(combinaciones)
print(radios_de_giro)
print(turn_rates)

print(
    (f"La combinacion {combinaciones[minimo_radio_de_giro_idx]} "
     f"tiene el radio de giro menor {minimo_radio_de_giro} "
     f"aunque tiene un turn rate de {turn_rates[minimo_radio_de_giro_idx]}")
     )
print()
print(
    (f"La combinacion {combinaciones[minimo_turn_rate_idx]} "
     f"tiene el turn rate menor {minimo_turn_rate} aunque tiene un "
     f"radio de giro de {radios_de_giro[minimo_turn_rate_idx]}")
     )
```

Salida:

> ```
> [[1 4]
>  [1 5]
>  [1 6]
>  [2 4]
>  [2 5]
>  [2 6]
>  [3 4]
>  [3 5]
>  [3 6]]
> [ 1.4627847   1.16915571  0.97320408  5.85113881  4.67662285  3.89281633
>  13.16506232 10.52240141  8.75883673]
> [39.24713548 49.10390357 58.99082264 19.62356774 24.55195178 29.49541132
>  13.08237849 16.36796786 19.66360755]
> La combinación [1 6] tiene el radio de giro menor 0.9732040815863825 aunque tiene un turn rate de 58.99082264
>
> La combinación [3 4] tiene el turn rate menor 13.082378493149275 aunque tiene un radio de giro de 13.16506232
> ```